# Enqueue celery task from other project

Tags: python, celery

I have a project using celery to process tasks, and a second project which is an API that might need to enqueue tasks to be processed by celery workers. 
However, these 2 projects are separated and I can't import the tasks in the API one.

I've used Sidekiq - Celery's equivalent in Ruby - in the past, and for example it is possible to push jobs by storing data in Redis from other languages/apps/processes if using the same format/payload.

Is something similar possible with Celery ? I couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in celery using `send_task` or `signatures`. Assuming `fetch_data` is the function in a separate code base, you can invoke it using one of the below methods

`send_task`

```
celery_app.send_task('fetch_data', kwargs={'url': request.json['url']})
```

`app.signature`

```
celery_app.signature('fetch_data', kwargs={'url': request.json['url']).delay()
```

You just specify the function name as a string and do not need to import it into your codebase.

You can read about this in more detail from https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/06/19/call-celery-task-outside-codebase/